# Hibernate: Perform criteria query with Sub-Select AND Left-Outer join?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria, left-join

Can I perform a Criteria query with Sub-Select AND Left-Outer join?

For example, I have A 1-many B 1-many C.

With Criteria.createAlias ("b", "b",  Criteria.LEFT_JOIN) I can perform **Left Outer** join.

With Criteria.setFetchMode ("b", **org.hibernate**.FetchMode.DEFAULT) I can perform Join with the default fetching strategy. I assume that having set @**org.hibernate.annotations**.FetchMode.SUBSELECT in both A.B and B.C is enough (is it?).

Question 1: Why does **org.hibernate**.FetchMode not have SUBSELECT option, whereas the **org.hibernate.annotations**.FetchMode does?

Question 2: Can I perform a Criteria query with Sub-Select AND Left-Outer join?

Comment: wouldn't the result of a left outer join(a -> b) be  the same as left outer join(a -> b -> c)?

Answer (score 2):

Criteria and `org.hibernate.FetchMode.SELECT` does nothing. The only option for Criteria is `org.hibernate.FetchMode.JOIN`. I do lazy initialization for Criteria results manually:

```
for (Entity e : result) {
 Hibernate.initizalize(e.getProperty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.FetchMode` has the same option under a different name, [`SELECT`](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html#SELECT).